# In DB2, how to import data from a .ixf file with updates on primary key

Tags: sql, database, db2, data-import, data-export

I have 2 tables: TABLE_1 and TABLE_2, all have same field: ID (primary key) and NAME. I want to import the data from TABLE_1 to TABLE_2 and I assume TABLE_1 has all the latest data. So I need to insert or update the records in TABLE_2 by primary key, delete is not needed. And I need to use .ixf to complete this task. 
As right now, I am just manually export the .ixf file from TABLE_1 as C:\table_1 and using 
IMPORT FROM "C:\table_1" OF IXF MODIFIED BY INDEXSCHEMA=DB2ADMIN METHOD P (1, 2) MESSAGES "C:\dblog.txt" INSERT INTO DB2ADMIN.TEST_2 (ID, NAME); 
Anything I can add into this sql statement to do inserts and updates on primary key?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMPORT` is not an SQL statement, it's a DB2 Command.

Have you tried reading the [manual for the `IMPORT` command](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html) to look at what options you have when performing an import?  Perhaps searching for `INSERT_UPDATE`?